# do fixmbr and fixboot change the list of oper. systems on start?

Tags: windows-7, boot, mbr

I have added new components in my computer and now I cannot start window 7, but I can Ubuntu, system repair cannot fix the problem. Then I read [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/startup-repair-cannot-repair-this-computer/718e1c0c-a907-404e-b48e-700e4e65c248?auth=1)

I want to try these commands:
 `bootrec /fixmbr` 
`bootrec /fixboot` ,

but I'm afraid to loose access to Ubuntu. Does these commands change list of operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

Windows systems won't recognise linuxes. Open a terminal instead in ubuntu, and type "sudo update-grub". It will look for operating systems and put both windows and ubuntu in the GRUB bootloader.

Comment: I have windows in bootloader list, it is not the problem. My computer resets every time when I start windows, and system repair cannot fix problem.

Comment: If you put new motherboard or cpu in your computer then you should reinstall Windows, then restore GRUB. If not, I'm not sure what is the problem but I'm sure it's with the Windows itself, not with the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking those commands won't change the list of operating systems.

But they **will** change **which list is used.** After running those commands your MBR will point to the Windows bootloader and not use the Grub bootloader.

You will indeed lose access to Ubuntu and as tvili999 recommended you should reinstall/fix Windows then use a Ubuntu disk to restore Grub.